# probability calibration using CalibratedClassifierCV for lightgbm

Tags: python, probability, calibration, lightgbm

I am trying to use sklearn's CalibratedClassifierCV() with lightgbm as below:

```
clf = LGBMClassifier(
boosting_type= 'gbdt',
objective= 'multiclass',
num_class=5,
metric= 'multi_logloss',
learning_rate= 0.05,
max_depth= 7,
num_leaves= 60,
feature_fraction= 0.7,
bagging_fraction= 1,
bagging_freq= 20,
nthread=4,
n_estimators=50)

calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, method='isotonic', cv=5)
calibrated_clf.fit(train_df[v1], train_df['label'])
```

However it's throwing me error, because there are some categorical variables, which lightgbm can handle efficiently without having to convert into one hot encoding but CalibratedClassifierCV not.

error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'RC'`

It's calling sklearn's validation.py which is throwing error at step, because calling astype float on string object:

```
if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
    array = array.astype(np.float64)
```

Is there a way I can handle this problem without converting into numeric variables? I am avoiding converting categories to numeric, as there are more than 10000 categories

Comment: please post the full error message that you are getting, including the full traceback.

Comment: Not in the inbuild CalibratedClassifierCV. But you can take a look at source code and modify it to remove the checks it does.